# Get build.gradle file as a .class file

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, jvm

I have a gradle file which prints "Hello World"

```
task hello << {
    println "Hello World"
}
```

This script is written in groovy. As I know we can get the output of Test.groovy into Test.class as it uses JVM. So my question is how to get the .class file of build.gradle file? Is there any specific command which I need to provide to the gradle demon?

Comment: it's impossible, but why do you need that? why not to use usual groovy if you wand something to compile?

Comment: a build.gradle is not a groovy script. It's a DSL who is interpreted by the Gradle framework.
your `println "hello"` is only a closure running into a framework

Comment: @daggett well I think at some point gradle will convert this groovy scipt to .class coz at last JVM is the one who does the work right? so there should be a .class file at the end. Am I right?

Comment: @JorgeAguileraGonzalez Yeah but at some point it should be converted to java byte code so that JVM can run this. Gradle is written in java and groovy uses JVM soIthink the final work is done by the JVM. So there should be a .class file

Comment: daggett and JorgeAguileraGonzalez are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that Gradle scripts (build.gradle, init script or settings script)  will be compiled into Java bytecode, during the [Gradle build initialization phase](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:initialization). The result *.class* files are generated by Gradle into internal "script" cache directory structure under ${user.home}/.gradle/caches/${gradle.version}/scripts.

But this compilation process is something internal to Gradle implementation, it's not exposed through the DSL or from API (as far as I know): you can find some implementation details in the *core* submodule from Gradle source code : see internal package https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/groovy/scripts

I don't think you can access these *.class* files programatically, even by hacking Gradle core implementation, but as others said in comments: why would you need that??

Comment: Well I just need it. I need to see the Java code by decompiling .class and see how the delegations works and etc.

Comment: you will find the .class where I have written, problem is that they are generated in directories with random names like "bk37q0xkx1tpx4ubnd22xfo5s" , it will be hard to locate the .class related to your specific build script. good luck ;)